# Eclipse Neon ignoring eclipse.ini -vm

Tags: java, eclipse

Well, today I added Java 10 to my Windows 10 machine and it broke eclipse Neon. My copy of Neon doesn't work with Java 10, so I explicitly ask it to use Java 8 in eclipse.ini. What am I doing wrong? I'm stumped. Neon keeps trying to use Java 10 to launch, regardless of my -vm setting.

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

log output after failed launch with Neon trying to use Java 10:

> !SESSION 2018-05-11 17:25:40.179
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400 java.version=10.0.1
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws
>   win32 -arch x86_64
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-05-11 17:25:42.747 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct    at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)

This is the message I get from Eclipse when it crashes. 
[image]

If I change JAVA_HOME and the java bin on my path to Java8's directories, Neon will run. So it seems to be reading env vars over the ini file, which seems backwards to my understanding of eclipse's vm hunting procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Move the line `--launcher.appendVmargs` two lines higher, above `-vm`.

See [Eclipse Wiki: Eclipse.ini - Specifying the JVM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM):

> The -vm option must occur ***after*** the other Eclipse-specific options
>   (such as `-product`, `--launcher.*`, etc), but ***before*** the `-vmargs` option,
>   since everything after `-vmargs` is passed directly to the JVM.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly, that is actually how I had my .ini file set up. I moved the -vm option up, and around to other locations trying to get lucky and cause a change. I'll update my .ini file in the question to reflect the current state.

Comment: I see. Strange. Does it work if you run Eclipse from the command line via `eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe"`? Does it work if you create a subdirectory `jre` in your Eclipse installation directory, copy everything from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121` into this newly created directory and in `eclipse.ini` remove `-vm` and the following line? What is the output of `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe" -version`?

Comment: It launches fine from the command line via `eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe"`. 

output: `C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
`

Comment: It does not launch with the 8 jdk inside jre, in the installation directory. Tries to use java 10 producing the same error message. But, it will launch if I only copy the the 8 jre directory into the my eclipse installation dir.

Indeed Strange.